# Map a url to a subdomain (NGINX)

Tags: php, configuration, nginx, subdomain, configuration-files

I know this question has been [asked before on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711666/mapping-subdomains-to-urls-with-nginx) but I'm having trouble replicating it on my server.

What I'm trying to do is when the user goes to `medicine.example.com`, the subdomain should be mapped to `example.com/sites/medicine`.  So the URL the user sees is `medicine.example.com`. 
index.php is stripped off via PHP.

The below code gives me a `502 bad gateway` error.

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name medicine.example.com;

    location / {
        rewrite             ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
        proxy_pass_header   Set-Cookie;
        proxy_pass          https://example.com/sites$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Ideally, the solution would be a wildcard/regex-based such that more than just `medicine.example.com` could be mapped. Thoughts?

Comment: Wouldn't a `proxy_pass` value of simply `https://example.com/sites/medicine/$uri;` work (without the rewrite)? Btw, are you looking at a redirect or really a proxy?

Comment: @Jack thanks, no go didn't work. also where is `$request_uri` vs. `$uri` variables coming from? i've never really understood this?

Comment: I **don't** want to redirect the url. I want to keep it as it is, `medicine.example.com`. Btw, I don't know what a proxy is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you want the URL in the browser to stay the same you don't need to do a rewrite. So you just need this (@Jack had an extra / in front of $uri).

$scheme should return http or https depending on what the user typed

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name medicine.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass     $scheme://example.com/sites/medicine$request_uri
}
```

here's a link on $uri versus $request_uri. bascially $uri does not include the arguments.
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24request_uri

Comment: what do your logs say? the problem might be with your `proxy_pass_header` statement. try `proxy_pass_header Host $host;` or even `proxy_pass_header Host example.com` I think you need to use add_header for cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The extra path will be automatically forwarded to the upstream server. So there is not need to attach $request_uri. Nginx is straightforward.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass     http://example.com/sites/medicine
}
```

[edit] also no need to use https for upstream server because it's wasting resource for ssl negotiation. Use http is better because your upstream server is internal. The traffic is safe.