# Using nginx to rewrite url to subdomain, make it accessible through both

Tags: nginx

Basically I have a catchall server block for say `*.example.com`. I want both `somename.com` and `somename.example.com` to work (ie for `somename.com/whatever` and `somename.example.com/whatever` to go through the same server block and lead to the same result) so there's no redirect. There might be several urls that need do be matched to different subdomains, so perhaps `map` may be the best way to go? I'm unsure, would appreciate any guidance on the matter!

EDIT: There is only one root that handles everything (and the app uses the subdomain as an important input), but it expects a subdomain, which is what makes rewriting the domain so that there is a subdomain so important.

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711666/mapping-subdomains-to-urls-with-nginx?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

A map is a good idea, but you might not need it. If you adopt a convention where `somename` is the name of your working directory, you could use a named capture as a variable root. The following regex `server_name` directive should match both `abc.example.com` and `abc.com`:

```
server {
    server_name  ~^(?<somename>[^\.]+)(\.example)?\.com$;
    root /var/www/$somename;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, there is only one root that handles everything, but it expects a subdomain, which is what makes rewriting the domain so that there is a subdomain so important.